# Largest Hausdorff quotient

Tags: gn.general-topology, reference-request

The inclusion of the full subcategory of Hausdorff topological spaces into the category of topological spaces has a left adjoint, which can be proven easily by the Adjoint Functor Theorem (see for example, S. MacLane, Categories for Working Mathematicians). To every topological space this left adjoint associates a Hausdorff space called the largest Hausdorff quotient.

Do you know a reference in which this left adjoint is constructed explicitly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ on your space $X$ such that $x\sim y$ iff $x$ and $y$ have the same image under all surjective continuous maps $f:X\to Y$ with codomain $Y$ a Hausdorff space. Put on the set $X/\sim$ the least topology which makes all those maps continuous, and you have the space you want. I doubt there is any actual reference for this.

Comment: (One can try to mod out $X$ by the relation "$x$ and $y$ cannot be separeted by disjoint open sets" —or its transtive closure, really— but the result is not Hausdorff; you can iterate this transfinitely, though, and you do get the space largest quotient. This is much more complicated/annoying/long to carry out)

Comment: There are some set-theoretic issues here, though they can be dealt with.  (You are currently quantifying over all compact Hausdorff spaces, which do not form a set.)

Comment: @Daniel, that is why I restricted to *surjective* maps. (In any case, the relation is well-defined even if one considers *all* maps and all $T_2$ sets, and one can easily show that there is a least topology satisfying the condition.  One *can* quantify over all spaces!)

Comment: Thanks, Marino! I was thinking in the way you describe in your second post and got stuck once I saw that the result is not Hausdorff. :) 

Answer (score 15):

Mariano already answered the question, but let me make two additional remarks:

1) Actually the proof of [GAFT](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem) is *constructive* and can be (at least sometimes) used to get explicitly a left adjoint functor. In this case, you can see directly the "big coequalizer" whose set-theoretic existence issue is dealt with the solution set condition: just consider all maps from your space $X$ into Hausdorff spaces which are *surjective*; this bounds the cardinality of the Hausdorff spaces, and thus up to isomorphism there is only a set of them.

2) Another construction of the left adjoint to $\mathsf{Haus} \to \mathsf{Top}$ works as follows: Let $X$ be a topological space, and consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ generated by: If $x,y$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets, then $x \sim y$. Then $H(X):=X / \sim$ has the property that every map from $X$ into a Hausdorff space uniquely factors through $X \to H(X)$. If $H(X)$ was Hausdorff, we would be done. But this is not always the case. Instead, we have to repeat this construction: $X \to H(X) \to H(H(X)) \to H(H(H(X))) \to \dotsc$, then take the colimit $H^{\omega}(X)$, and make again $H^{\omega}(X) \to H(H^{\omega}(X)) \to \dotsc ...$. You can continue this for every ordinal number. Since $X$ is a set and all these maps are quotient maps, at some stage we get an isomorphism, which is the desired Hausdorff quotient.

It is interesting *when* we arrive at this stage, see my question about the [nonhausdorff dimension](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11191/nonhausdorff-dimension).

Answer (score 2):

To augment very slightly Mariano's nice answer, Hausdorff quotients (as opposed to surjections) suffice.

To obtain the finest Hausdorff quotient of an arbitrary space $X$, take the quotient of $X$ by the intersection of all partitions of $X$ determined by quotient maps from $X$ with $T_{2}$ image.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I think it is relevant to mention the paper “A Universal Factorization Theorem in Topology” by Sharpe, Beattie and Marsden (*Canad. Math. Bull.* **9** (1966), 201–207): they describe how to (fairly explicitly) construct the smallest equivalence relation $R$ so that $X/R$ is $T_2$ (or various other separation axioms), relate it to the “obvious” equivalence relation (namely the one induced by “every pair of open sets containing respectively $x$ and $y$ intersect”; this is essentially what Martin Brandenburg says in his answer above) and they give an example where the two do not coincide.  Their result applies to various similar separation properties.

Comment: "above" is not a well-defined MO notion :)

Comment: For a simpler example where the quotient by the "obvious" relation is not $T_2$, see https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Hausdorffization (example repeated from 4.16 in Bart van Munster's https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/citations;jsessionid=068087C1854E2E685287F21A44F426DD?doi=10.1.1.728.5810)

Answer (score 0):

A good reference is §4.3 of : D. Huybrechts, *A Global Torelli theorem for hyperkähler manifolds (after Verbitsky)*. Seminaire Bourbaki Exp. No. 1040 Juin 2011 Astérisque No. 348 (2012), 375-403; arxiv:[1106.5573](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5573).

Comment: That doesn't look lke a good reference. It deals with a rather special case; the construction of $\approx$ certainly does not apply to a general topological space, and in fact the situation is such that the naive relation $\sim$ of non-separation *is* an equivalence relation, which seldom happens, and the quotient is Hausdorff, which happens even less :-)