# Generalization of analytic functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

It's been a long time since I posted the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435166/generalization-of-analytic-functors) on stackexchange.

Now I think it's better to adress it to you, in the hope I will reach the right audience: Martin's comment, albeit useful, didn't help me to satisfy my curiosity.

===

A functor $F\colon \bf Sets\to Sets$ is said to be *analytic* if it results from the left Kan extension of a functor $f\colon \mathbf{Bij}(\mathbb N)\to \bf Sets$ (the "species" of the functors $F$) along the natural inclusion $\mathbf{Bij}(\mathbb N)\to \bf Sets$, where $\mathbf{Bij}(\mathbb N)$ is the category having objects natural numbers and where $\mathbf{Bij}(\mathbb N)(m,n)$ are the bijective functions $\{1,\dots,m\}\to \{1,\dots,n\}$ (empty if $n\neq m$). Representing a left Kan extension as a coend it means that
$$
F(T)\cong \int^n T^n\times f(n)
$$
(the most of you will recognize the fact that a functor is "anaytic" if it can be written in Taylor form, and the coend is in a suitable sense exactly that Taylor series) This can be expressed replacing $\bf Sets$ with any symmetric monoidally cocomplete category: there is a functor $\mathbf{Bij}(\mathbb N)^\text{op}\times \mathcal V\to \mathcal V\colon (n,V)\mapsto V\otimes\dots\otimes V=V^{\otimes n}$, which allows to define 
$$
\int^n V^{\otimes n}\otimes f(n)
$$
for any "species" $f\colon \mathbf{Bij}(\mathbb N)\to \mathcal V$.

In the case of $\bf Sets$, it seems to be possible to extend the definition of an analytic functor to the case of an arbitrary cardinal $\kappa$:

1. the category $\mathbf{Bij}(\kappa)$ is defined to be the category having objects cardinals $<\kappa$ and $\mathbf{Bij}(\kappa)(\mu,\nu)$ bijections between those cardinals (hence empty if $\mu\neq\nu$).
2. I say that a functor $F\colon\bf Sets\to Sets$ is $\kappa$-analytic if it results from $\text{Lan}_jf$ in the diagram
   $$
   \begin{array}{ccc}
   \mathbf{Bij}(\kappa) &\to& \bf Sets \\
   \downarrow&\nearrow_F&\\
   \bf Sets &
   \end{array}
   $$
   $F(T)\cong \int^{\mu}T^\mu\times f(\mu)$ where $T^\mu$ is the product of $\mu$ copies of $T$, in the obvious sense.

Now my question: can I define something analogous in the case of a generic monoidal(ly cocomplete) category, maybe imposing some additional property? In the end all boils down to the possibility of defining a $\kappa$-fold tensor product $\otimes\colon \mathcal V^\kappa\to \mathcal V$, for any cardinal $\kappa$. Modules over a ring $R$ seem to have this "extension property", together with sets.

Being these two very explicit and natural examples of a monoidal category where "tensoring has an arbitrarily large arity", I think the problem has its own interest, and I would be surprised if the topic was new.

===

As I pointed out in the comments on math.SE, I was motivated by Martin's [topic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11767/infinite-tensor-products) about k-ary tensors in $Mod_R$ to pose the question in the form of a "k-ary tensor product". I think there is no hope to recover "usual properties"; it's better to think about an axiomatization of the structure I need, but for the moment I don't have the slightest idea. I repeat myself: on the one side I find quite astounding the lack of a theory of those monoidal categories where tensoring has an arbitrarily large arity, and on the other, it's obviously due to the absence of "good" properties for such a structure.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure this will meet your expectations, but maybe Mark Weber's [work on functors with arities](http://sites.google.com/site/markwebersmaths/home/familial-2-functors-and-parametric-right-adjoints) is relevant. See Remark 2.12 therein, in particular.

The upshot, if I'm correct, is that any analytic endofunctor $F$ obtained from $f$ as above may be recovered from a polynomial diagram along the lines of

$$1 \leftarrow D \to \int^{n} f(n) \to 1,$$

where $1 \leftarrow D \to \int^{n} f(n)$ is the comma cone from
the Yoneda embedding $1 \to Sets$ to the functor $\int^{n} f(n) \to Sets$ mapping $(n,x)$ to the finite ordinal $n$.

The functor $Sets \to Sets$ associated to such a diagram takes any set $X$, viewed as a functor $1^{op} \to Sets$, and

- restricts it along (the opposite of) $1 \leftarrow D$, then
- right extends it along  (...) $D \to \int^{n} f(n)$, and finally
- left extends it along (...) $\int^{n} f(n) \to 1.$

In our case, this should map $X$ to $\int^p X^p \times {f(p)}$, as desired.

So we obtain $F$ as a so-called *parametric right adjoint* functor (I think Mark now calls these *local right adjoints*). There is an even more general notion of *functor with arities*, defined in the particular case of monads in the above paper, and made more explicit in [Berger, Melliès, and Weber](http://sites.google.com/site/markwebersmaths/home/monads-with-arities).