# Infinite coproducts and monoidal structure

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

It is a well-known fact that on categories admitting all finite coproducts one can define a monoidal structure where the monoidal product is exactly the coproduct and the monoidal unit is the initial object.

For coproducts there is nothing that prohibits me from working with a countable (or even uncountable) number of objects. Now I was wondering if there exists any general theory on how this can be generalized to the monoidal context? (In general I have barely found anything on the extension of monoidal products to an infinite number of objects.)

This question popped up while I was studying monoidal posets (see *Seven Sketches in Compositionality* by Spivak & Fong: [http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/teaching/sp18/7Sketches.pdf](http://math.mit.edu/%7Edspivak/teaching/sp18/7Sketches.pdf)). On one hand I am interested in this question from an educational point of view because I would in general like to know how the concepts from monoidal category theory generalize to ''infinite products''. But on the other hand I am also interested from a professional point of view because not all operations I consider come from coproducts (e.g. the addition on $\mathbb{R}^+$) and hence I cannot resort to a description in those terms.

Comment: You can construct infinitary coproducts from finite coproducts and directed colimits in a straightforward fashion (it is say, in MacLane's book). My suggestion is to define infinitary monoidal products in the same way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\infty$-ary tensor product on a category](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106674/infty-ary-tensor-product-on-a-category)

Comment: This indeed gives an idea of what the infinitary construction would be (at least in abstract terms). I assume that the definition of infinitary (lax) monoidal functors will also be a suitable modification of the finitary definition from Leinster's *Higher operads, higher categories*?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.08787) might be of interest.